# How to import com.google.android package.?

Tags: android

I want to create an activity which will extends MapActivity class.
But I am unable to import `com.google.android.maps.MapActivity`

It is showing following error:

```
the import com.google can not be resolved
```

Comment: Do you have necessary libs added to yout project.

Comment: make sure you have create google APIs project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build you project with Google Api's Library. It looks you are building it with general Android Api.

Do the following steps to get rid of your error.

> Right Click on Project ---> Properties ---> Android ---> Select Google
>   Apis (any api level)--->Click Apply.

Comment: How to do that? I mean building an android project with google api's Library?

Answer (score 0):

Bring up your project properties, and go to Android. Do you have an Android target selected that includes the Google APIs? Perhaps you just have a generic Android target.

- First you have to make sure you have installed Google API
- Then set your project's properties in `Eclipse` to check off the Google APIs version of the SDK.
- and Make sure you have include this library in AndroidManifest FIle

  `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`